# Updating Firebase Data for Any User in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to allow documents (reports) that are created by a user to be viewed by other users and then updated with changes. The documents show up in a tableView that when selected show the appropriate data for that specific report loaded up in a ViewController. However when I go to select the update button within that ViewController of the individual report, the error comes back that no document can be found.

Below is the current variation of code I am working with for the update function.

```
private let database = Firestore.firestore()


private init() {}

// UPDATE REPORT
public func updateTheData(
    reportPost: ReportPost,
    thisReport: String,
    completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
){

    let data = [
        "id": reportPost.identifier,
        "title": reportPost.title,
        "timestamp1": reportPost.timestamp1,
        "address": reportPost.address,
        "customerPO": reportPost.customerPO,
        "authNum": reportPost.authNum,
        "contactName": reportPost.contactName,
        "contactPhone": reportPost.contactPhone,
        "modelNum": reportPost.modelNum,
        "serialNum": reportPost.serialNum,
        "addInfo": reportPost.addInfo,
        "equipProblem": reportPost.equipProblem,
        "action": reportPost.action,
        "followUp": reportPost.followUp,
        "techName1": reportPost.techName1,
        "techName2": reportPost.techName2,
        "techName3": reportPost.techName3,
        "techName4": reportPost.techName4,
        "timestamp2": reportPost.timestamp2,
        "timestamp3": reportPost.timestamp3,
        "timestamp4": reportPost.timestamp4,
        "milesTraveled1": reportPost.milesTraveled1,
        "milesTraveled2": reportPost.milesTraveled2,
        "milesTraveled3": reportPost.milesTraveled3,
        "milesTraveled4": reportPost.milesTraveled4,
        "travelTime1": reportPost.travelTime1,
        "travelTime2": reportPost.travelTime2,
        "travelTime3": reportPost.travelTime3,
        "travelTime4": reportPost.travelTime4,
        "siteTime1": reportPost.siteTime1,
        "siteTime2": reportPost.siteTime2,
        "siteTime3": reportPost.siteTime3,
        "siteTime4": reportPost.siteTime4,
        "serviceType1": reportPost.serviceType1,
        "serviceType2": reportPost.serviceType2,
        "serviceType3": reportPost.serviceType3,
        "serviceType4": reportPost.serviceType4,
        "timeTotal1": reportPost.timeTotal1,
        "timeTotal2": reportPost.timeTotal2,
        "timeTotal3": reportPost.timeTotal3,
        "timeTotal4": reportPost.timeTotal4,
        "partNum1": reportPost.partNum1,
        "partNum2": reportPost.partNum2,
        "partNum3": reportPost.partNum3,
        "partNum4": reportPost.partNum4,
        "quantity1": reportPost.quantity1,
        "quantity2": reportPost.quantity2,
        "quantity3": reportPost.quantity3,
        "quantity4": reportPost.quantity4,
        "price1": reportPost.price1,
        "price2": reportPost.price2,
        "price3": reportPost.price3,
        "price4": reportPost.price4,
        "priceTotal1": reportPost.priceTotal1,
        "priceTotal2": reportPost.priceTotal2,
        "priceTotal3": reportPost.priceTotal3,
        "priceTotal4": reportPost.priceTotal4,
    ]

    let docRef = database.collection("reports").document(thisReport)
    
    docRef.updateData(data) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error updating document: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully updated")
        }
    }

}
```

For Reference, this is how a report is saved and uploaded to the database in Firebase.

```
    // FSR REPORT POSTING
public func insert(
    reportPost: ReportPost,
    email: String,
    completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
) {
    let userEmail = email
        .replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "_")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "_")
    
    let data = [
        "id": reportPost.identifier,
        "title": reportPost.title,
        "timestamp1": reportPost.timestamp1,
        "address": reportPost.address,
        "customerPO": reportPost.customerPO,
        "authNum": reportPost.authNum,
        "contactName": reportPost.contactName,
        "contactPhone": reportPost.contactPhone,
        "modelNum": reportPost.modelNum,
        "serialNum": reportPost.serialNum,
        "addInfo": reportPost.addInfo,
        "equipProblem": reportPost.equipProblem,
        "action": reportPost.action,
        "followUp": reportPost.followUp,
        "techName1": reportPost.techName1,
        "techName2": reportPost.techName2,
        "techName3": reportPost.techName3,
        "techName4": reportPost.techName4,
        "timestamp2": reportPost.timestamp2,
        "timestamp3": reportPost.timestamp3,
        "timestamp4": reportPost.timestamp4,
        "milesTraveled1": reportPost.milesTraveled1,
        "milesTraveled2": reportPost.milesTraveled2,
        "milesTraveled3": reportPost.milesTraveled3,
        "milesTraveled4": reportPost.milesTraveled4,
        "travelTime1": reportPost.travelTime1,
        "travelTime2": reportPost.travelTime2,
        "travelTime3": reportPost.travelTime3,
        "travelTime4": reportPost.travelTime4,
        "siteTime1": reportPost.siteTime1,
        "siteTime2": reportPost.siteTime2,
        "siteTime3": reportPost.siteTime3,
        "siteTime4": reportPost.siteTime4,
        "serviceType1": reportPost.serviceType1,
        "serviceType2": reportPost.serviceType2,
        "serviceType3": reportPost.serviceType3,
        "serviceType4": reportPost.serviceType4,
        "timeTotal1": reportPost.timeTotal1,
        "timeTotal2": reportPost.timeTotal2,
        "timeTotal3": reportPost.timeTotal3,
        "timeTotal4": reportPost.timeTotal4,
        "partNum1": reportPost.partNum1,
        "partNum2": reportPost.partNum2,
        "partNum3": reportPost.partNum3,
        "partNum4": reportPost.partNum4,
        "quantity1": reportPost.quantity1,
        "quantity2": reportPost.quantity2,
        "quantity3": reportPost.quantity3,
        "quantity4": reportPost.quantity4,
        "price1": reportPost.price1,
        "price2": reportPost.price2,
        "price3": reportPost.price3,
        "price4": reportPost.price4,
        "priceTotal1": reportPost.priceTotal1,
        "priceTotal2": reportPost.priceTotal2,
        "priceTotal3": reportPost.priceTotal3,
        "priceTotal4": reportPost.priceTotal4,
    ]
    
    database
        .collection("users")
        .document(userEmail)
        .collection("reports")
        .document(reportPost.identifier)
        .setData(data) { error in
            completion(error == nil)
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is pretty vague and for us to help we need clarity. What is "it" in this statement *it cannot find the report*? There are so many things that could go wrong with that code as well we need details. For example if `thisReport` is nil, nothing will be written. So - your best bet is to do some troubleshooting; add a breakpoint to your code and step through it line by line inspecting the vars and code execution and when something doesn't look right, update the **question** with that info and then maybe we can help.

Comment: @Jay "it" was referring to the firebase / the error I was receiving. I updated the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Again, we need clarity of troubleshooting as well. Is `thisReport` valid and what you expect? Is `userEmail` valid and resolve to a valid documentId? (as a side note, and in general using email addresses as documentId's is a BAD idea) Is `reportPost` valid? Can you see the data in the Firebase console? Also, this `.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "_")` is going to be problematic as _ is a valid char anywhere and also if the user changes their email address, you'll never find their document.

Comment: @Jay For updateTheData() function, none of it does what I want it to do which is to be able to update any post a user clicks on. The insert() function does work by placing the document (ReportPost) into each user's collection, such as Users > User Email > Reports > and then the list of individual reports that user created. The individual document ID's are a randomly generated UUID.String. All the data is correctly appearing within Firebase and I can create a new document for any user, I am just unable to edit those fields.

Answer (score 0):

When the report is first inserted, it's stored at this path

```
database.collection("users")
        .document(userEmail)
        .collection("reports")
        .document(reportPost.identifier)
        .setData(data)
```

which is

```
users/the_email/reports/some id
```

but then when you're attempting to update that report it's at this path

```
database.collection("reports")
        .document(thisReport)
        .updateData(data)
```

which is

```
database/reports/some id
```

and that's two different locations.

*To update data, it needs to point to the same document reference.* so the data needs to be updated at the same location it was initially written to

```
database.collection("users")
        .document(userEmail)
        .collection("reports")
        .document(reportPost.identifier)
        .updateData(data) //<- same path as it was initially
```

As a side note, the documentId is both being stored as the documentId as well as within the document in the "id" field and there's no reason to do that. A documentId is static and if it's known, you can get to that data directly without a query.

I would also suggest not using users emails as documentIds'; user emails can change and if that happens you won't be able to find the report. Additionally, if you want to update that, you'll have to find every occurance of that old email in the entire database, read it and it's child data in, delete it and re-write it. What a pain.

Also, substituting _ for @ and . in the email address may work to a point but if want to get back that email address, there could be multiple _ in the address; how would you know which _ was the @ and which one was actually part of the email address.

```
some_person@thing.com -> some_person_thing_com = some@person_thing.com?
```

**EDIT**

Per the question, suppose there are a series of reports that are 1) shared amongst users 2) the creating user can edit their own reports

Here's one option for storing the reports

```
reports (collection)
   document_0 //a document with an auto-generated documentId
     created_by_uid: "uid_0"
     report_info: "some info about this report, fields etc"
   document_1
     created_by_uid: "uid_1"
     report_info: "some info about this report"
```

The reports collection can be read by any user, which meets criteria 1. It's easy to get the reports created by user with uid_0 as a simple query can be run against the reports collection where created_by_uid = uid_0.

Here's the code with an object to hold the report data: documentId the report_info (the report data) and a field to track who created the report. Suppose user with uid_0 is logged in and wants to edit a report. We'll load all of the reports uid_0 created and store them in an array:

```
class ReportClass {
    var id = ""
    var report_info = ""
    var created_by_uid = ""
}

var reportArray = [ReportClass]()

func readReports(forUid: String) { //pass in uid_0
    let reportsCollection = self.db.collection("reports")
    reportsCollection.whereField("created_by_uid", isEqualTo: forUid)
    reportsCollection.getDocuments(completion: {documentSnapshot, error in
        for doc in documentSnapshot!.documents {
            //note we don't need the created_by_uid because it's not going to change
            let report = ReportClass()
            //keep track of the document Id
            report.id = doc.documentID as! String
            //the report info which the user is changing
            report.report_info = doc.get("report_info") as! String
            self.reportArray.append(report)
        }
    })
}
```

now the reports are presented to the user so they can select one and edit it. Upon saving we update the ReportClass object report_info field with the new data the user input and pass the object to a function to update that report

```
func updateReport(theReport: ReportClass) {
    let reportsCollection = self.db.collection("reports")
    let thisReport = reportsCollection.document(theReport.id)
       //the report document path is reports/documentId
    thisReport.updateData(["report_info": theReport.info]) //only update the report_info field
}
```

The key here is we load in and store the users reports, keeping the report documentId in the object. That keeps track of the path to the report

```
reports/report id/id, report_info and created_by_uid fields
```

then when the report is ready to be written, we derive the path from the documentId stored in the object so the path is the same.

I did a lot of this long-hand, but you should be using Codable objects as it makes populating them a snap

See [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/)

Comment: For updating the data, how do I get it to know which document location it is in and the documentID so that I can push an update? 

For using the emails as documentID this is going to be used by employee emails so they won't be changing. However what would you suggest I do to layout documents that are for individual users?

Comment: Employee emails change. *betty_smith@company.com* gets married and becomes *betty_jones@company.com*. Happens all of the time. To answer you question; to update a document, you need to write it out to the same location where it was read in from - just like a folder in a computer; if you store document A in folder A, read it in, modify it and store it in Folder B, that's now a totally different document at a different location. See my answer - write the data back to where it was to start with.

Comment: You can lay out documents for users however you like; if they are not shared then you could store each document within that users document *users/uid/documents/doc0....doc1....doc2* etc. Or, you could have a *documents* collection and store each users documents within that *documents/uid/doc0..doc1...doc2* etc. As you can see though, leveraging a users `uid` is the key as it will never change for any reason.

Comment: Yes so how do I go about getting it to determine which user email and documentID it needs to be in the path in order to update? 

I tried to do the same function I had in [insert()] except instead of [.setData(data)] I did [.updateData(data)] but that still didn't work

Comment: Unless there just isn't a way to do that - but then I am unsure of how to get individual user's reports to show up on their profile.

Comment: @SamMacInnes I think you may be making it more difficult than it is; you just need to keep track of what the documentId the report is, and establish a path to that report. When writing back out you write the report back out to the same path. Let me update the question with an example and see if that makes it more clear.

Comment: Okay so just to confirm I want to actually create two collections, one of users and the other of reports? Then I'm pulling user reports based on the created_by_uid field

Comment: @SamMacInnes The overall design is really up to you; one of the requirements was - *to be viewed by other users* - and that's way easier if all of the reports are in a common collection instead of burying a users reports within a single users email address. That makes it a snap to allow everyone to see all of the reports and also super easy to put in rules that only allow the user that created the report to be able to edit it. But - we don't know your entire use case so it's a bit of guesswork on my part.